# Calculate object property values based on user id

Tags: javascript

Got an object containing a user id for each user and prices, would like to create a new object/array for each user (no duplicates) and be able to calculate the total sum of price for each user. Tried using Object.values() with map and filter but can't get it to work properly

```
{
     "data": {
         "item1": {
             "price": "20",
             "user": "user1"
         },
         "item2": {
             "price": "10",
             "user": "user2"
         },
         "item3": {
             "price": "50",
             "user": "user1"
         }
     }
}
```

Output something like this:

```
{
     "users": {
         "user1": {
             "totalSum": "70",
         },
         "user2": {
             "totalSum": "10",
         }
     }
}
```

I'm thinking about using map to present the "users"-data, maybe an array would be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using function `reduce`.

**Important:** The attribute `price` is a String, this approach uses object `Number` to convert that value to a numeric one.

```js
var obj = {  "data": {    "item1": {      "price": "20",      "user": "user1"    },    "item2": {      "price": "10",      "user": "user2"    },    "item3": {      "price": "50",      "user": "user1"    }  }};

var result = Object.keys(obj.data).reduce((a, k) => {
  if (a.users[obj.data[k].user]) {
    a.users[obj.data[k].user].totalSum += Number(obj.data[k].price);
  } else {
    a.users[obj.data[k].user] = {
      "totalSum": Number(obj.data[k].price)
    }
  }

  return a;
}, {
  'users': {}
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important; top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage ```reduce, more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

code (haven't tried this)

```
var data = JSON.parse(mainObj).data;

var usersWithTotalExpenditure = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(result, key) {
    var currentItem = data[key];
    var useName = currentItem.user;
    var price = Number(currentItem.price);

    if (userName in result) {
        result[userName].totalSum += price;
    } else {
        result[userName] = {
            totalSum: price
        };
    }

    return result;
}, {});

var resultObject = {
    users: usersWithTotalExpenditure
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a forEach loop. This relies on Javascripts powerful OR operator, which coerces the first half of the expression to false if the current user's price is not defined (meaning it is a user the loop hasn't encountered before)

```
`c is your initial object's data, output is empty object` 
const c = obj.data;
var output = {};
Object.keys(c).forEach((val) => {
    output[c[val]["user"]] = parseInt(output[c[val]["user"]]) + parseInt(c[val]["price"]) || parseInt(c[val]["price"]);
})
```